# Using homemade scripts without regular output vector in the processing modeler

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

As far as I know, there is no processing script that is able to create PostGIS type output layers including views and materialized views. Therefore I decided to create some alternative PostGIS geoprocessing algorithms (e.g. 'Point on surface'):

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# define Interface
##PostGIS spatial processing (QGIS 2.x)=group
##Point on surface (PostGIS)=name
##Input_layer=vector
##Output_relation_type=selection Table;View;Materialized View
##Output_schema=string public
##Output_layer=string pg_pointonsurface
##Output_primary_key=string gid
##Output_geometry_column=string geom
##Attributes_to_keep_(comma_separated_list)_[non_working_dummy]=string None
##Add_output_layer_to_map=boolean true

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import *

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

import psycopg2

# get input parameters from GUI
inlayer = processing.getObject(Input_layer)
inlayer_dp = inlayer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()

# get database parameters (input layer)
db_name = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).database()
db_host = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).host()
db_port = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).port()
db_user = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).username()
db_password = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).password()

# get input layer parameters
inlayer_schema = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).schema()
inlayer_table = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).table()
inlayer_uic = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).keyColumn 
inlayer_geom = QgsDataSourceURI(inlayer_dp).geometryColumn()
inlayer_crs = inlayer.crs().postgisSrid()

# get output relation parameters
outrelationtype = Output_relation_type
if outrelationtype == 0:
    outrelationtype = 'TABLE'
elif outrelationtype == 1:
    outrelationtype = 'VIEW'
elif outrelationtype == 2:
    outrelationtype = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW'

outschema = Output_schema
outlayer = Output_layer
outpk = Output_primary_key
outgeom = Output_geometry_column
outadd = Add_output_layer_to_map

# check input layer
provider = inlayer.dataProvider()
if provider.name() != 'postgres':
        raise RuntimeError('Input layer \'' + inlayer.name() + '\' is not a PostgreSQL/PostGIS relation :(')

# connect to database
conn = psycopg2.connect( "dbname={0} host={1} port={2} user={3} password={4}".format( db_name, db_host, db_port, db_user, db_password ) )

# create and run query
with conn.cursor() as curs:
    sql = """CREATE {0} "{1}"."{2}" AS SELECT
    row_number() over() AS "{3}",
    ST_PointOnSurface("{4}")::geometry(Point, {5}) AS "{6}"
FROM "{7}"."{8}";
    """.format( outrelationtype, outschema, outlayer, outpk, inlayer_geom, inlayer_crs, outgeom, inlayer_schema, inlayer_table )

    progress.setInfo('Executing SQL statement ... \n')
    progress.setInfo(sql)
    curs.execute(sql)
    progress.setInfo('... done. \n')

    # create primary key, sequence and spatial index for relation type 'TABLE'
    if outrelationtype == 'TABLE':
        sql_pk = """ALTER TABLE "{0}"."{1}" ADD CONSTRAINT "{1}_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("{2}");""".format( outschema, outlayer, outpk )
        curs.execute(sql_pk)

        sql_seq = """CREATE SEQUENCE "{0}"."{1}_{2}_seq" OWNED BY "{0}"."{1}"."{2}";
        SELECT SETVAL('"{0}"."{1}_{2}_seq"', (SELECT MAX("{2}") FROM "{0}"."{1}"));
        ALTER TABLE "{0}"."{1}"
        ALTER COLUMN "{2}" SET DEFAULT nextval('"{0}"."{1}_{2}_seq"'::regclass);
        """.format ( outschema, outlayer, outpk )
        curs.execute(sql_seq)

        sql_sidx = """CREATE INDEX "sidx_{1}_{2}" ON "{0}"."{1}" USING GIST ("{2}");""".format( outschema, outlayer, outgeom )
        curs.execute(sql_sidx)

    # commit changes if everything went OK
    conn.commit()

# load layer
if outadd:
    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection( db_host, db_port, db_name, db_user, db_password )
    uri.setDataSource( outschema, outlayer, outgeom, None, outpk )
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer( uri.uri(), outlayer, "postgres" )
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to fully integrate these PostGIS scripts in the processing modeler, because they don't create regular output vectors. Is there any way to access the output function of the processing modeler?

[image]

Comment: why are you doing this in the QGIS processing modeler and not in a SQL file run against the database (and even wrapped in python?)